# Apache Rewrite Numeric Arguments To Root

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

We keep finding requests coming in like:

```
https://www.example.com/?1537249139=
```

The numbers in the query string parameter appear to be random timestamps.  This is costing us in our prerender budget so we would like to 301 redirect these back to root.  I have tried this:

```
   RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([0-9]*)=$
   RewriteRule / [L,R=301]
```

But it doesn't work.  Any ideas?

Comment: Your RewriteRule is wrong, it is lacking either the pattern or the substitution URL. You need two “parameters” before the flags, you provided only one.

Comment: I don't understand.  There is only one parameter and it never has a value.  Just the equal sign.

Comment: I am not talking about the URL parameters, I am talking about what you have written after `RewriteRule`

Comment: Actually you could have easily found out the actual issue if you were monitoring your http server's error log file. That is where you find specific error messages in such case. _You cannot operate a production system without monitoring that central file!_

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteRule / [L,R=301]
> ```

This won't match the example URL. You are missing the first argument (*Pattern*) that matches against the requested URL-path:

> RewriteRule *Pattern* *Substitution* [*flags*]

Your example URL is for the document root only (`/`), so this needs to be written like the following in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^\d+=$
RewriteRule ^$ / [R=301,L]
```

In `.htaccess`, the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *Pattern* does not include the slash prefix (which is why your original directive would not have matched).

Note that this is a "redirect", not a "rewrite" as stated in your question title.

However, if these are completely invalid requests (perhaps even by a bot?) then would it not be preferable to simply return a 403 or 404? For example:

```
RewriteRule ^$ - [F]
```

OR

```
RewriteRule ^$ - [R=404]
```

?

Reference:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule